# TinyMCE and TradingEye - HTML Tags Rendered in Content

Tags: html, tags, tinymce

I have TinyMCE installed in a Trading Eye installation instead of the default FCKEditor but when you enter anything in to the textareas and click update, the front end editor contains `<p>` tags and the HTML editor contains `<p>&lt;p&gt;`, meaning when viewing the content on the site itself, the

tags are rendered as text and not HTML. Is there anyway to fix this issue please guys.

My TinyMCE init code is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mainDescription",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,nonbreaking,wordcount,advlist",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true
    });
```

Thanks in advance guys. :)

Comment: Are you putting the html in <code> blocks? You should generally use the rich text editors native UI for paragraphs etc since that's what it's there for. Check TinyMCEs FAQ for help on this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_encodes_.3C_and_.3E_characters_in_written_text.3F

Comment: One more resource that may help: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25837